# Not able to run Cassandra locally using brew

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

I am trying to run Cassandra on my machine. Tying cqlsh gives me this error,

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1:9042': error(61, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
```

Running `cassandra -f` hangs.

I installed cassandra using `brew install cassandra`.
Also I have done all of the followings:

- Killed docker instance
- Uninstall and reinstall Cassandra (deleted all the Cassandra data and filles from my machine)
- Restarted my machine
- Purged docker data

I don't know why still I am running into this. Running `brew services list` shows:

```
  Name       Status  User   Plist
cassandra  started aanish /Users/aanish/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.cassandra.plist
mysql      stopped
mysql@5.7  started aanish /Users/aanish/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql@5.7.plist
postgresql stopped
```

Comment: check Java version - Cassandra 3.x works only with Java 8

Answer (score 1):

The `cqlsh` connection error indicates that `localhost` is not listening on port `9042` (Cassandra's CQL client port). The most likely reason is that the Cassandra process is not running.

You can confirm whether the Java process is listening on port `9042` if you run the following command in a terminal:

```
$ sudo lsof -nPi -sTCP:LISTEN
```

You will need to review the `system.log` (typically in `/var/log/cassandra`) to figure out what is going on with Cassandra.

Note that if you set `rpc_address` in `cassandra.yaml` to the IP of your mac, you need to specify that address when you connect with `cqlsh`. For example:

```
$ cqlsh 10.1.2.3
```

Comment: I confirmed that there is no process running in 9042 port. Also my rpc_address is set localhost.

Comment: If there is no process listening on port `9042`, it means that Cassandra is not running. Again, you need to check the logs to figure out why it's shutdown or not running. Cheers!